# Use jQuery slider with Bootstrap loaded, a conflict happens

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried yesterday but I got 0 answers, the topic is dead but I'm still looking for a solution of my problem. Take a glance at the following:

[image]

As you can easily perceive, my jQuery sliders received like 'cuts' on their handles' right and bottom sides. Another weird thing is that all the texts I had are now with smaller letters and maybe a tad change happened with their color as I see back-colored text on few nuances down. All this happens when I load the bootstrap libraries, so it surely should be coming from BS. Please, answer me, because I'd like to move on but this up to somewhere spoils the appearance of my project. I suspect there is a hidden conflict between jQ UI and BS, what do you think?
 Here's how I load the libraries:

```
 <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
 <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

P.S. BS I load from server, links are taken from w3. However, exactly the same happens when I load them from my computer. If I remove BS js, sliders don't appear at all. The same happens also when I delete the normal jQ libraries. I need the normal jQ and comes out that BS needs its. Help. :)

Comment: try changing the order of your css?

Comment: Where we can see your code? Can you make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Why not load the jquery-ui styles after bootstrap? This way styles will be overridden properly by conflicting jquery ui styles unless bootstrap tagged them as !important

Comment: @MaxBumaye  what do you mean? I've now tried to rotate the libraries of css but it didn't change anything. The code is around 500 lines, so what intriguates you mostly: sliders, css of the sliders and the boostrap navbar?

Comment: @bingo, now did this, a lots of rotations of the jquery libraries - none of them worked, I mean the what you suggested also didn't work :(
P.S. The only redundant thing was that jq 1.3., I got rid of it.

Comment: for example your jquery could have a .slider class and your bootstrap could have a class equal in name. the css which is loaded last, will overwrite the previous behaviour

Comment: @MaxBumaye I renamed .slider which I had to .sliderB and changed it everywhere but it was the same. Those sliders are with custom interface, a.k.a. I load separate images meaning that maybe this bewilders BS I don't know... hm

Comment: @MaxBumaye you were near, I've just found that: The issue is that jQuery UI also has a slider widget initialized using slider() method, So there is a namespace collision.
However the guy from the topic was trying to make bootstrap slider by having jquery lib loaded, whereas I'd like to do the reverse - to have a jq slider and to use BS for another completely different thing - to build a menu. Now what? :D